# why returning None in functions python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, printing

[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZyoy.png)
I was having problem when I run this code I raise exception in function then why none is printing

[sec image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8V29F.png)
And in this case none is not printing.. pls help

Comment: Your observation is incorrect. You invoke the function twice.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the tour and see [ask]. This question will be closed because you've posted images of code, and there is a lack of clarity to what you are asking. See how to create a [mcve], and edit the question to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when a python function does not have a return statement it automatically return None.

In the first image, the `print(numcheck(5))` pass the assert but the function return None so it printed None but `print(numcheck(-5))` did raise the exception.

In the second image `print(numcheck(-5))` raise directly the exception so python did not print anything.

Comment: but when I raise error in function you can see in first image.it returns none if it encounters error it should not procced... pls see

Comment: @ChotuRai because you invoke the function twice, once it returns, once it raises. Please follow a few python tutorials and get used to a debugger.

Comment: so first time its not give any error, second time it encounter error so why print is giving none you may see in first image. but in second image its not giving can you explain pls

Comment: pls see both images

Comment: both console outputs are the result of the first line `print(numcheck(5))`: first you print done inside the function, then the return value which is None. You do not get any output from the `-5` line since it raises an error

Comment: oo i got it friend thankyou. i was thinking when second time i was calling the function i was getting none.